# Trying to mimic TurtleBot Follower

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, turtlebot, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to mimic the work of turtlebot_follower by copy-pasting the code from the follower.cpp in the same package.
The code is below:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.h" 
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h" 
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include "dynamic_reconfigure/server.h"
#include "turtlebot_follower/FollowerConfig.h"

#define min_x -0.2
#define min_y 0.1
#define max_x 0.2
#define max_y 0.5
#define max_z 1.0
#define goal_z 0.6
#define x_scale 7.0
#define z_scale 2.0


typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
ros::Subscriber sub_;
ros::Publisher cmdpub_;
geometry_msgs::Twist cmd;


int main(int argsc, char **ararr)
{
 ros::init(argsc, ararr, "foll");
 ros::NodeHandle nh;
 
 
 void cloudcb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr&);
 cmdpub_ = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist> ("cmd_vel", 1);
 sub_= nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/camera/depth/points", 1, cloudcb);
 while(ros::ok())
 {
    ROS_INFO("GOING GOING BOING!!!");
    ros::spinOnce();
 }
 
 int t = 5;
 ros::Rate rate(1);     
    
}

void cloudcb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
    PointCloud cloud;
    pcl::fromROSMsg (*input, cloud);
    //X,Y,Z of the centroid
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double z = 0.0;
    //Number of points observed
    unsigned int n = 0;
    //Iterate through all the points in the region and find the average of the position
    BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, cloud.points)
    {
      //First, ensure that the point's position is valid. This must be done in a seperate
      //if because we do not want to perform comparison on a nan value.
      if (!std::isnan(x) && !std::isnan(y) && !std::isnan(z))
      {
        //Test to ensure the point is within the aceptable box.
        if (-pt.y > min_y && -pt.y < max_y && pt.x < max_x && pt.x > min_x && pt.z < max_z)
        {
          //Add the point to the totals
          x += pt.x;
          y += pt.y;
          z += pt.z;
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (n)
    { 
      x /= n; 
      y /= n; 
      z /= n;  
      
      ROS_DEBUG("Centriod at %f %f %f with %d points", x, y, z, n);
      
      
      cmd.linear.x = (z - goal_z) * z_scale;
      cmd.angular.z = -x * x_scale;
      cmdpub_.publish(cmd);
      ROS_ERROR("GOT INPUT!");
    }
    else
    {
      ROS_DEBUG("No points detected, stopping the robot");
      cmdpub_.publish(geometry_msgs::Twist());
    }
}
```

I have editted the callback in this one to get a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 data instead of the pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ data that is there in the original follower.cpp file.

I have tried with both the cases. I have found that the callbacks occur two slowly (once every 3-5 seconds), when I used the pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ datatype for the callbacks and the callbacks never occurred when I used the sensor_msgs::PointCloud datatype.

Is there a problem with the code?
The turtlebot_follower launch file (follower.launch) works great!!!
But this one, apparently having the same logic as the other, works too slow. The robot tries to reorient itself once in every 3-5 seconds.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36205/trying-to-mimic-turtlebot-follower/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-11**:
@McMurdo Please don't shout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off sensor_msgs/PointCloud and sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 are not compatible. If you want to use the two of them you need to subscribe and republish.

For the speed of the transport the subscription in the follower is chosen to use the pcl::PointCloudXYZ specificially because that is the datatype which the OpenNI nodelet is publishing.  And by subscribing with the same datatype as is being published in the same process (using nodelets) the follower gets the data with zero copies(just a pointer pass).  If you change the data type you will incur the costs of serializing, copying and deserializing, which is the performance difference you are seeing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-03-12**:
Two years hence, I understand the point.